# How to substitute the small letters in a string with capital letters and also to find out no of substitutions

Tags: python, regex, string

Here is my problem: I have a string. Then I want to substitute the small letters with respective capital letters and also want to know the number of substitutions it had to do for the string.

```
S = "ABCdefGHijKLmNop"

Output string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
```

and the number of substitutions.(six in this case)

Then I tried with re.sub:

```
New = re.sub("[a-z]","[A-Z]",S)
```

But the output looks like:

```
ABC[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]GH[A-Z][A-Z]KL[A-Z]N[A-Z][A-Z]
```

I also tried to sole, using replace function of string but that didn't work out either.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.#str.isupper) to return a copy of the string in uppercase and [`islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.#str.islower) with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) to get the number of substitutions.

```
>>> S = "ABCdefGHijKLmNop"
>>> S.upper()
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
>>> sum(1 for i in S if i.islower())
8
```

Another way to do this is using a generator function and the little-known [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) class.

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> it = count(0)
>>> def substitute(string):
...     for char in string:
...         if char.islower():
...             next(it)
...             yield char.upper()
...         else:
...             yield char
... 
>>> ''.join(substitute(S))
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
>>> it
count(8)
```

#### What performance says?

```
%%timeit 
capitalize(S)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.74 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
S.upper()
sum(1 for i in S if i.islower())
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
''.join(substitute(S))
it
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.9 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of substitutions as well as the substitutions, you'll need to define your own function:

```
def capitalize(string):
    substitutions = 0
    newstring = ""
    for char in string:
        newstring += char.upper()
        if char.islower():
            substitutions += 1
    return newstring, substitutions
```

To use:

```
>>> string = "ABCdefGHijKLmNop"
>>> newstring, substitutions = capitalize(string)
>>> newstring
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
>>> substitutions
8
```

Comment: I suppose it's not the "pythonic" way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex, I think the easiest way would be using lambda:

```
import string
S="ABCdefGHijKLmNop"
len(filter(lambda x: x in string.lowercase, S))
callback = lambda pat: pat.group(1).upper()
new = re.sub(r'([a-z])', callback, S)

>>> 8
>>> print new
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```